# How to draw a square inside a square?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

[pink square is the task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPyjx.png)I am trying to draw a square inside a square using turtle graphics. I couldn't draw exactly like the original one.
Here is my code

```
import turtle
win = turtle.Screen()
tess = turtle.Turtle()

for two in range(12):

for _ in range(4):
    tess.forward(20)
    tess.left(90)
tess.penup()
tess.goto(-7,-4)
tess.pendown()
for _ in range(4):
    tess.forward(35)
    tess.left(90)
tess.penup()
tess.goto(-14,-8)
tess.pendown()
for _ in range(4):
    tess.forward(50)
    tess.left(90)
tess.penup()
tess.goto(-21,-16)
tess.pendown()
for _ in range(4):
    tess.forward(70)
    tess.left(90)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good example for better living through *stamping* instead of *drawing*:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('lightgreen')

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.color('pink', 'lightgreen')

for size in range(100, 0, -20):
    turtle.shapesize(size / CURSOR_SIZE, outline=3)
    turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: little bit confuse 100/20=5 now  what's the next value which div from 20 again??

Comment: @learner, the confusion is likely due to how `shapesize()` works.  It doesn't take a size in pixels, but rather a number to multiply the size of an existing cursor by.  To convert to pixels, you need to know the size of the existing cursor (`CURSOR_SIZE`) and divide the size in pixels by that to get the multiplier.

Answer (score -1):

I think, my code solution your problem.

```
from turtle import *

def draw_square(a,color,x,y):
    penup()
    goto(x,y)
    setheading(90)
    backward(a//2)
    setheading(0)
    backward(a//2)
    pendown()
    pencolor(color)
    for _ in range(4):
        forward(a)
        left(90)

draw_square(20,"pink",0,0)
draw_square(50,"pink",0,0)
draw_square(70,"pink",0,0)
draw_square(90,"pink",0,0)
draw_square(110,"pink",0,0)
```